# Python request - specifying what to get in xml response

Tags: python, xml, api

I created request in my python code, that gives me response like bellow:

```
<tasks>
    <task>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>test task 1</name>
        <sysID>410d6c0bc0a801c901838d8ac43b3279</sysID>
        <type>Windows</type>
        <version>2</version>
    </task>
    <task>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>test task 2</name>
        <sysID>410d6880c0a801c90196685fcc1ecb47</sysID>
        <type>Windows</type>
        <version>9</version>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

It lists all the tasks.

But I need to get just  the list of the names of the tasks. Is there a way how to specify it in request? Or do I need to parse it after?

Or more general question: is there a way how to define in a request which tags and attributes will be returned as response?

My request now:

```
response = req.post(uac_path, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pw), 
headers=headers, data=prop_params, verify=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the server's responsibility to decide what to return, rather than the client's. Unless the server gives you some way to specify what should be returned (for instance if it's a [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) API) you'll need to parse the response yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the response first. there are several packages in Python to parse XML:

```
 - xml.dom
 - xml.dom.minidom
 - xml.dom.pulldom
 - xml.sax
 - xml.parser.expat
 - xml.etree.ElementTree
```

you can choose any one of them or other thirdparty tools in Python